# Error generating dependencies with make

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to implement the non-recursive make solution outlined in the paper "[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)". I'm currently stuck on getting the *.d dependency files to generate. I've provided the makefile, sample module.mk and error below. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
MODULES :=      \
    module1     \
    module2     

# define compiler
CC = /opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.1

# exclude the following warnings for clang
CLANG_NO_WARN =                 \
    -Wno-c++98-compat           \
    -Wno-weak-vtables           \
    -Wno-padded                 \
    -Wno-global-constructors    \
    -Wno-exit-time-destructors   

# look for include files in each of the modules
CFLAGS +=                                                               \
    -g -Weverything -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ $(CLANG_NO_WARN)    \
    -I../ -I/usr/local/include $(patsubst %, -I%, $(MODULES))

# linker flags
LDFLAGS :=                                                  \
    -stdlib=libc++                                          \
    -L/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib -L/usr/local/lib

# extra libraries if required (each module will add to this)
LIBS :=                     \
    -lboost_program_options \
    -lboost_system          \
    -lglog                  \
    -lpugixml

# source files to be compiled (each module will add to this)
SRCS := \
    Main.cpp

# include the descriptions for each module
include $(patsubst %, %/module.mk, $(MODULES))

# determine the object files
OBJS := \
    $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(filter %.cpp, $(SRCS)))

# link the program
prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# include the C include dependencies
include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

# calculate C include dependencies
%.d: %.cpp
    depend.sh `dirname $*.cpp` $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp > $@  

----------

#!/bin/sh

# Evaluate dependencies for use by the makefile

echo "Called"
DIR="$1"
shift 1
case "$DIR" in
    "" | ".")
        $CC -MM -MG "$@" | sed -e 's@ˆ\(.*\)\.o:@\1.d \1.o:@' ;;
    *)
        $CC -MM -MG "$@" | sed -e "s@ˆ\(.*\)\.o:@$DIR/\1.d \ $DIR/\1.o:@" ;;
esac    

------------

# module.mk
SRCS += \
    Algo.cpp        \
    CommandHandler.cpp  \
    Exchange.cpp        \
    TCPSocket.cpp       \
    TradingEngine.cpp       

----------

$ make
makefile:68: Main.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: view_string.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: Algo.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: CommandHandler.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: Exchange.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: TCPSocket.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: TradingEngine.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: Exchange.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: Requests.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: TickCapture.d: No such file or directory
makefile:68: types.d: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `types.d'.  Stop.
```

**UPDATE**
Finished makefile and sample module.mk

```
$cat makefile
# executable name
BINARY := my_prog

# clang config
CLANG := /opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.1

CLANG_WARNINGS :=               \
    -Wno-c++98-compat           \
    -Wno-weak-vtables           \
    -Wno-padded                 \
    -Wno-global-constructors    \
    -Wno-exit-time-destructors

CLANG_CFLAGS := \
    -g -Weverything -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

CLANG_LDFLAGS := \
    -stdlib=libc++

# generic compiler config
CC :=       $(CLANG)
CFLAGS :=   $(CLANG_WARNINGS) $(CLANG_CFLAGS) 
LDFLAGS :=  $(CLANG_LDFLAGS)

INCS :=                             \
    -I../                           \
    -I/usr/local/include            \
    $(patsubst %, -I%, $(SUBDIRS))

LIBS :=                                 \
    -L/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib \
    -L/usr/local/lib                    \
    -lboost_program_options             \
    -lboost_system                      \
    -lglog                              \
    -lpugixml

# list subdirectories in which to look for dependencies
# must define SRCS first as subdirs will append to this
# their src files
SRCS := Main.cpp

SUBDIRS :=  \
    module1 \
    module2

include $(patsubst %, %/module.mk, $(SUBDIRS))

# derive object files from srcs
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(filter %.cpp, $(SRCS)))

# link the program
$(BINARY): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# include generated dependency files
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS)

# generate include dependencies
%.d: %.cpp
    ./depend.sh `dirname $*.cpp` $(INCS) $*.cpp > $@

# compile
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCS) $< -c -o $@

# clean, obviously
clean:
    rm -f $(BINARY)
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm -f $(DEPS)

# et voila!   

-----

$cat module1/module.mk
SRCS_PATH := module1
SRCS += \
    $(SRCS_PATH)/Algo.cpp           \
    $(SRCS_PATH)/CommandHandler.cpp \
    $(SRCS_PATH)/Exchange.cpp       \
    $(SRCS_PATH)/TCPSocket.cpp      \
    $(SRCS_PATH)/TradingEngine.cpp
```

Comment: I think you might need to put quotes around `\`dirname $*.cpp\``

Comment: Try moving the "include $(OBJS:.o=.d)" to a point in the makefile after the "%.d: %.cpp" conversion rule.

Comment: @jpm This doesn't work, the back ticks need to be expanded out

Comment: @ShaunMarko The ordering doesn't matter, the %.d rule will be searched for when the .o=.d is evaluated

Comment: Gnu make reads a makefile in two phases. During the first phase it will include all other makefiles indicated by the "include" directive. In your case, the include directive includes the %.d dependency files. The %.d dependency files are created from %.cpp files with the "%.d: %.cpp" recipe, but that recipe is not run until the second phase of make execution. Recipe execution is deferred to the second phase.

Comment: @ShaunMarko If this is the case then surely the paper referenced in the question would never be possible? I'm sure the include must invoke the %.d rule, no? Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if some module adds `types.cpp` to `SRCS`, even though no such source file exists.

As for the warnings, the first time you run this makefile, the dependency files (`foo.d`) do not yet exist, so Make complains that it can't `include` them. It's not a problem, and the warnings won't appear in subsequent runs when those files do exist beforehand. To supress the warnings entirely, change `include` to `-include`.